# React Native. No carga mapa de react-native-maps

Tags: google-maps, react-native

Estoy intentando mostrar un mapa en react-native, cuando inicio la aplicación nunca lo muestra, solo aparece una [pantalla blanca con el logo de google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdSKM.jpg) , y cuando giro el celular me muestra el icono de que esta [cargando](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCFSU.jpg). No tengo restricciones en mi [Api Key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ird0N.jpg), ¿Como puedo solucionar esto?

```
    import React from 'react';
    import MapView from 'react-native-maps'
    import { View } from 'react-native';

    const App = () =>
        (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <MapView
                    style={{ flex: 1 }}
                    region={{
                        latitude: 37.785834,
                        longitude: -122.406417,
                        latitudeDelta: 0.0143,
                        longitudeDelta: 0.0134,
                    }}
                    showsUserLocation
                    loadingEnabled
                />
            </View>
        );

    export default App;
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, traduce tu pregunta, el idioma oficial del sitio es el "español", saludos.

Comment: Hola Edgar, hay detalles que no mencionas, como ¿Cómo fue tu proceso de instalación? También es importante saber desde qué dispositivo estás intentando hacer la prueba, ya que no funciona igual en Android o iOS, normalmente para Android si usas un emulador, necesitas que este tenga incluido Google Play, del resto, bajo una buena configuración, normalmente todos los errores se deben a algo referente al API KEY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error era en la Api Key, no tenia habilitado el Maps SDK for Android. Lo deshabilite ya que no lo estaba usando y cuando quise probar mi aplicación en android nuevamente me mostraba solo el logo de google sin cargar el mapa.

De acuerdo a la documentación,  si el logo de google se muestra y el mapa no, es señal de que hay un error en la api key

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md